# jQuery disable ability to select date in date selector

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am using the [kamadatepicker](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Persian-Jalali-Calendar-Data-Picker-Plugin-With-jQuery-kamaDatepicker/) jQuery plugin, I want to create a function that if I give it a date, it will be disabled in the day button calendar of the same date.

For instance, If I input the date `1399/02/03` to the function, the date should be disabled in the date selector.

HTML:

```html
<input  type="text" id="datebox" />
```

jQuery:

```js
 let options = {
    nextButtonIcon: "img/timeir_next.png",
    previousButtonIcon: "img/timeir_prev.png",
    forceFarsiDigits: true,
    gotoToday: false,
    markHolidays: true,
    markToday: true,
    disableHolidays: false,
}
kamaDatepicker('datebox', options);
```

Comment: From the documentation that you've linked to, that datepicker library does not have the ability to disable dates at all, let alone dynamically after initialisation. You will need to use a different datepicker library which does have that feature.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I do not know what calendar to use, I searched a lot but I did not find anything. Do you know?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any datepicker libraries which use the format in your example.